# sum and len unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str

Tags: python

```
`list = []
with open("ads.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as ads:
    first= ads.readline()
    for i in ads:
        i = i.strip().split(";")
        list.append(i)
    print(f"3.: aaa: {len(lista)} db")
    height = [i[2] for i in lista]
    print(f"4.: average: {sum(height)/len(height)}")`
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str
can you help

Comment: Sounds like `lista` is a mix of ints and strings, or maybe just strings.  You can't take the average of non-numeric values like you're trying to do.  Unfortunately, you didn't include the code that generates `lista` so it's impossible to debug that.

Answer (score 0):

agree with @Samwise, the list - `height` should contain numbers. the code is being stuck at `sum(height)`